# How to Manipulate parts of a shape with Raphael/svg?

Tags: raphael

For example:

Lets say I use Raphael to draw a green square.

Is is possible to make a hole in the center of the square?

I would need the hole to be a "real" hole and not just another object that is masking out part of the square.

Edit: So, the answer given below is: Not Possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use path to achieve this effect.

for instance:

```
paper.path(0,0,"m 71.584821,226.66072 c -1.662,0 -3,1.338 -3,3 l 0,339.6875 c 0,1.662 1.338,3 3,3 l 362.562499,0 c 1.662,0 3,-1.338 3,-3 l 0,-339.6875 c 0,-1.662 -1.338,-3 -3,-3 l -362.562499,0 z m 179.843749,80 c 53.65052,0 97.15625,38.99733 97.15625,87.125 0,48.12767 -43.50573,87.15625 -97.15625,87.15625 -53.65052,0 -97.15625,-39.02858 -97.15625,-87.15625 0,-48.12767 43.50573,-87.125 97.15625,-87.125 z").attr({fill:'#f00'});
```

For your information, this path was created with Inkscape.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the path after it has been created? For example, first, a green square is shown. Next, the hole appears inside the square.

Comment: Yes, you can change the path string.

Comment: Is it possible to make the circle "fade out" of the green square, instead of just disappearing? Can you use the square as a basis for a clipping path?

Comment: I think you'll need to combine two elements : the "path with a hole" and a circle. You'll next animate the circle's opacity.